# How to correctly embed image in html email

Tags: php, html, email, embed

I have some trouble to correctly embed images in html/php email.
My .php file just sends out a few text emails. But I want a picture in there.

`<img src="http://website/image.jpg">` works so far but outlook blocks the image and I have to click download images every time.

So I found out that this is the behaviour of linked images. What I need is an embeded image.

`<img src="image.jpg">` seems easy but does not work. The image is in the root directory of the index.php but the Mail does not contain the image. Just an error appears: "image cant be displayed".

I swear I googled for 2 hours now. How do the companies do that with their signature.

I appreciate your help.

Comment: signature coming from outlook or other third party software configuration.

Comment: You will need to attach that image to the email for it to be displayed - could you show how you're sending the email?

Comment: @TristanSeifert Thank you so much. It makes sense of course. I got it with PHPMailer and attachment!

Answer (score 1):

I've done the company signature couple days ago and found a lot of problems. 
For instance, you can set background-image and gmail and most of the email managers will display it, but outlook will not.
For images isn't the same.
Outlook will display your image, usually when it's https://...
In my case I was using firebase hosting to locate the images and 0 problems with that.

```
<img data-imagetype="External" src="https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/..." class="x_gmail-CToWUd">
```

I use this signature in gmail, and outlook is displaying that `<img>` tag without any problems, and no need to make any attachment.
The data-imagetype is added from outlook when receiving the email and the class x_gmail... too.

Hope this will help you, if not I'll try to find a better solution for you.

Answer (score 0):

Most email clients block images as a default. It’s up to the user or administrator to overcome this behavior. You can’t override it in email.

Answer (score 0):

```
To add an image with both dark and light versions in an HTML email template, you can use the following steps:

Create two versions of your image, one for the light background and one for the dark background.

Use the HTML picture element to specify the two versions of the image. The picture element allows you to provide different sources for the image based on different conditions.



    <picture>
       <source srcset="image-dark.jpg" media="(prefers-color-scheme: dark)">
       <img src="image-light.jpg" alt="example image">
    </picture>
```